# What species of three-tailed flying insect is this?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, zoology

What species of insect is this? Collected in spring in the United Kingdom near a river in an urban area during the late afternoon. They were flying up and down in the air.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Three tails mean [ephemeroptera (mayfly)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayfly). I don't know what species though. Mayflies can pop up very numerous all of sudden as they sometimes all hatch at the same time and fly around like crazy.

Comment: Nice pictures! What is the approximative size?

Comment: 1 cm body + 2 cm tail

Comment: It only has a day to live. Let it go.

Comment: I did, don't worry. I don't keep animals unless I know how to take care of them. It was quite agitated but it flew away from my pot extremely fast into the sky.

Comment: @charlesdarwin Is the order mayfly good enough or are you hoping for a more detailed answer?

Comment: The more detailed the better but I'll accept your answer until there is a better one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this [list of mayflies of the UK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mayflies_of_the_British_Isles), your mayfly is from the genus *Ephemera*.  Of the three species listed at that site for the UK, the closest match is to *Ephemera vulgata*, and it looks quite close.  The image of *E. vulgata* below is from Wikipedia [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ephemera_vulgata_Hald_s%C3%B8_2009-06-07_1.jpg).

[image]